# Как отправить письмо на почту с хостинга hoster.kz?

Tags: веб-программирование, email, хостинг

Не могу отправить письмо на почту с хостинга hoster.kz, однако на локальном сервере все письма таки отправляются в temp/email в виде txt файлов, то бишь скрипт работает, но на хостинге проблема, вот что пишет техподдержка:
Не работает отправка почты через функцию php mail?
Если у Вас на сайте существует рассылка почтовых сообщений, есть форма регистрации пользователей, функция "оставить отзыв", либо c сайта отправляются какие-нибудь данные пользователям, Вам нужно сделать следующее:

1. Создать у себя на хостинг аккаунте почтовый ящик.
2. Прописать данный почтовый ящик в скрипте рассылки (в частности в поле "FROM"), настройках CMS и указать его в качестве "e-mail администратора" в www домене.
   Помогите пожалуйста понять, что они здесь написали ?

Comment: через smtp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет.

1. Зайди на свой аккаунт и создай почту типа "info@мойдомен.kz".
2. В CMS, когда отправляешь почту, указывай, что будешь отправлять с этой почты. Сейчас ты пытаешься отосласть с почты, с которой ты не создал. В CMS надо настроить модуль, наверное, называется FormBuilder, который отправляет почту. Так вот там ты настроиваешь, с какой почты на какую почты отсылать. Указывай свои данные, но для начала проверь, правильно ли ты создал почту.

Comment: Создал Почтовый Ящик: info@afdcredit.kz, теперь в скрипт надо вписать адрес выше, в поле From? А в поле To могу вписать любой адрес почты?

Comment: да конечно, любой, на какой хотите, на во From обязательно ваш

Comment: СПАСИБО ВАМ ОГРОМНОЕ, вроде вещь простая, но без ваших развернутых ответов я так бы и не понял, вы единственный, кто разжевал мне ответ, остальные просто отправили меня куда-подальше, еще раз спасибо!

Comment: не вопрос, сам сталкивался с такой ситуацией, что просто тупо ссылки кидают